# Validation Rule is failing tests on Stage, but not on Dev or Prod -- everything appears to be the same across all 3

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Due Date is a Required Field: [Due_Date__c]
Stack Trace: Class.TestDataFactory.createSiteSurvey: line 205, column 1 Class.Answer_TriggerTest.initData: line 10, column 1
```

None of the failing test cases - which call TestDataFactory.createSiteSurvey - contain 'runAs'.

Why does this error happen on Stage, but not on Prod or Dev. All 3 environments have the same Validation Rule:

```
AND($Permission.STRT_Manager,
ISNULL(Due_Date__c))
```

All have the same Permission Set which has Custom Permission "STRT_Manager"

Here's the code. It fails on insert survey here:

```
  public static Site_Survey__c createSiteSurvey(Account site,
      Questionnaire__c questionnaire) {

    Site_Survey__c survey = buildSiteSurvey(site, questionnaire);
    insert survey;
    return survey;
  }
```

Comment: There's always a difference, it's just a matter of finding it.  Is that your whole validation rule?  Or an abbreviated version? (a lot of people leave out detail when asking questions here).  When were the sandboxes refreshed/created? Like any troubleshooting, you need to isolate the variables. is it failing due to the custom permission, or the due date? is there any other logic in the org that might be impacting it?  who is running the tests? no one can answer your question here because we'd need access to the whole system to see what else is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best if you check in your own Anonymous Developer Console

```
Boolean hasCustomPermission = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('STRT_Manager');
```

This will check if the username you logged in salesforce has the specific custom permission you created as true or false.

If Boolean result is TRUE then that is why your test classes are failing. Then you can explore https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_FeatureManagement.htm for more info.